# How to display my iOS apps list to table view controller in my app?

Tags: ios, rss, uitableview, itunes-store

What I want to do is figure out one way to display all my iOS apps in iTune store in my application with UITableViewController.

For example, when I search in iTune with keyword "xcodechina",it will display all published products in iTune store with table view. I just want to do this in my own application.

If there is specific xml linkage just like RSS, that will be easy to do that, but seem like there is not.

Any other clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provide an iTunes WeServices API you can find at this address: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

To find iOS apps, the keyword is "software", you can also search for iPad software with "iPadSoftware" or mac with "macSoftware".

For example to find the game "Pentarow" on iPad :

http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/wsSearch?country=FR&media=software&entry=ipadSoftware&term=pentarow